# on and off checkboxes group

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I look at the internet up side down and couldn't find a reasonable script to perform this that although it is a simple routine I don't know how to implement.

As you see the code bellow after the implementation of the ID issue I would like to automatically uncheck the "smart search" checkbox and check the RegEx checkbox when one of the three RegEx checkboxes is clicked AND when one of the three checkboxes is unchecked to turn everything to the original state where the "smart search" checkbox is the only one selected again. Too confusing? –

In other words I have a field with 5 checkboxes commands where the #5 is checked by default.
I want when the #1,2 or 3 is clicked this will uncheck #5 and check #4 AND IF any other #1,2 or 3 is unchecked this return to the original state with #5 checked. Is this comprehensible?

```
<head>

<!-- CHECKBOXSES REGEX 1 -->

<script type="text/javascript">

function getVal(bu){

var el=document.getElementById('col12_filter_prospective');
var i=0, c;while(c=document.getElementById('chk'+(i++))) 
{el.value=(bu.checked)? bu.value : null;c!=bu? c.checked =false : null;
}
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr id="filter_col12_prospective" data-column="12">         
<td colspan="4"><hr width="100%"  size"0.5px"> 
</td>           
<tr>
<tr>
<td>City</td>
<td align="center">             
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="[^***]" id="chk0" onclick="getVal(this)" title="[^***] Replace (***) with the word to excluded from search.">  
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="/whatever[^s]*./" id="chk1" onclick="getVal(this)" title="/whatever[^s]*./ Find (whatever) word that ends with (s) or any other combination.">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="/***/" id="chk2" onclick="getVal(this)" title="/***/ Replace *** for specific word to be found.">
<br>
<input type="text" class="column_filter_prospective" name="col12_filter_prospective" id="col12_filter_prospective">
</td>               
<td align="center" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter_prospective" id="col12_regex_prospective">
</td>
<td align="center" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter_prospective" id="col12_smart_prospective" checked="checked">
<br>
</td>
</tr></table>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should take care of checking/unchecking routine I guess:

```
function check() {
    var isChecked = checks.some(function (el) {
        return el.checked;
    });
    document.getElementById('col12_regex_prospective').checked = !isChecked;
    document.getElementById('col12_smart_prospective').checked = isChecked;
}

// run initial check
check();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/94rpLosn/

See simplified example below.

```js
var checks = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name=chk]'));

function getVal() {
    check();
}

function check() {
    var isChecked = checks.some(function (el) {
        return el.checked;
    });
    document.getElementById('col12_regex_prospective').checked = !isChecked;
    document.getElementById('col12_smart_prospective').checked = isChecked;
}

check();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" onclick="getVal(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" onclick="getVal(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" onclick="getVal(this)">
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" id="col12_regex_prospective">
<input type="checkbox" id="col12_smart_prospective" checked="checked">
```

Comment: Excellent, many thanks. but see, perhaps I wasn't clear. I need 1 OR 2 OR 3, they suppose to load RegEx patterns in the city field and again if 1 or 2 or 3 is checked it changes smart to reggae and if the last used alone 1,2 or 3 is unchecked this will reset the original state with smart checked. Super, super thanks.

Comment: Excellent but how to I to avoid ID conflict to run the same function in several fields? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I have to care  about ID conflicts with this both scripts. Is important to mention that this feature will be installed in several fields in the same form.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function getVal(bu, id){
      var el = document.getElementById(id);
      
      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName(bu.className);
      for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        el.value = (bu.checked)? bu.value : null;
        checkboxes[i] != bu ? checkboxes[i].checked = false : null;
      }
    }
 
  </script>

Comment: var checks = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name=chk]'));

function getVal() {
    check();
}

function check() {
    var isChecked = checks.some(function (el) {
        return el.checked;
    });
    document.getElementById('col12_regex_prospective').checked = !isChecked;
    document.getElementById('col12_smart_prospective').checked = isChecked;
}

check();